# Как собрать проект в aide на Android?

Tags: android, ide, java

У меня вопрос по aide для Android... Я совчем новичок в программировании на Java. Хотя не столько в программировании,  сколько в архитектуре проэктов на этом языке. В общем,  столкнулся с проблемой: даже простой "Hello,  World! " в арk собираться не желает.  Процесс компиляции останавливается на 20%. Вот папки и файлы,  которые находятся у меня в только что созданном проекте MyApp:

```
/bin/classes... пустая папка;  
/gen/com/mycompany/myapp/R.java;  
/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png;  
/res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png;  
/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png;  
/res/layout/main.xml;  
/res/values/strings.xml;  
/src/com/mycompany/myapp/MainActivity.java;  
/proguard.cfg;  
/.classpath;  
/.project;  
/project.properties;  
/AndroidManifest.xml;
```

Подскажите,  что со всем этим делать,  где здесь должен быть мой скрипт,  что это вообще за файлы,  и почему этот проект не компилируется.  Спасибо.

Вот ссылка на ппроект: http://msg.dimonvideo.ru/sklad/files/1941157/216_myapp.zip

Comment: Зазипуйте весь проект и выложите архив куда-нибудь. Могу посмотреть.

Comment: @xyanight, Ваш проект отлично собирается AIDE, возможно Вы используете модифицированную глючную версию. Попробуйте http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=319369

Answer (score 1):

У топикстартера явная склонность к мазохизму, ибо собирать проект (тем более начинающему) под [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=ru) - то есть в смартфоне (sic!) это как говорится уметь еще надо.

Вы бы уважаемый, сначала собрали просто под обычной виндой, а уж потом извращались/упражнялись. Начните [отсюда](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: Жесть, извращение...

Comment: @Barmaley, AIDE вполне успешно создает сама новый проект чистый (компилирующийся), поэтому единственный мазохизм в неудобности экранной клавиатуры в сравнении с компьютерной. Тут скорее всего дело к багрепорту идет.

Comment: А вообще, вспоминаю времена, когда на работе торчал сутками без доступа к компьютера, домой приходил и не до программирования было, а вот на работе можно было вполне себе успешно писать программки на python под symbian прямо на телефоне.  
И вот что любопытно- написание на телефоне мне казалось как-то теплее и ламповее что-ли, чем с компьютера.

Comment: Я вырос на AIDE.. Сначала казалось все невозможным. Однако))